# Display LinearLayout with AChartEngine graph in two different activites

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout

I have a main activity which displays `AchartEngine` graph in a `LinearLayout` located inside `main.xml` file. I am interested in displaying that `LinearLayout` in another activity using a different xml file.

Is there a way to doing so?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your shared element in Fragment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

Comment: It will take some further reading. But I know its possible now :-)